# How can I code k-map for 4 variable function in C?

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a 4-variable kmap but I am not sure how to create the left side (00->10) of kmap. Thank you for your help. :)

Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
unsigned int w, x, y, z;
unsigned int f;

/* Print header for K-map. */
printf("         yz      \n");
printf("     00 01 11 10 \n");
printf("   ______________\n");

/* row-printing loop */
for (w = 0; 2 > w; w = w + 1)
{
    for (x = 0; 2 > x; x++){
         printf("w=%u%x | ", w,x);
    }


    /* Loop over input variable b in binary order. */
    for (y = 0; 2 > y; y = y + 1)
    {
        /* Loop over d in binary order.*/
        for (z = 0; 2 > z; z = z + 1)
        {
            /* Use variables b and d to calculate *
             * input variable c (iterated in      *
             * Gray code order).                  */
            /* CALCULATE c HERE. */
            y = x^z;

            /* Calculate and print one K-map entry *
             * (function F(a,b,c) ).               */
            /* INSERT CODE HERE. */
            f = (w|~x) & (~w|~y) & (w|~x|~y) & 1;
            printf("%u  ", f);
        }
    }

    /* End of row reached: print a newline character. */
    printf("\n");
}

return 0;
}
```

For further information, this is what I have to do "Demonstrate its work using f(w,x,y,z) = xy'+w'z and g(w,x,y,z) = w'xyz'+ w + x' as examples"

Comment: What is a k-map? Do you mean a Karnaugh Map? Do not use abbreviations or obscure terms without defining them or providing a reference. (And be precise in your language; you have “k-map” in one place, “kmap” in another, and “K-map” in a third.)

Comment: For a fixed case as shown, you can generate the values for the left column of labels simply by storing them in an array, as with `unsigned int g[4] = { 0, 1, 3, 2 };`, and looking them up by row number (`g[0]` for row 0, `g[1]` for row 1, and so on). However, from the comment “Use variables b and d to calculate input variable c (iterated in Gray code order)”, I expect your class has discussed Gray code recently. Likely some method to generate Gray code or to convert binary (0, 1, 2, 3, 4,…) to Gray code (0, 1, 3, 2, 6,…) was discussed. Use that method.

Comment: `y = x^z;` <<-- you are messing with the loop variable here. (maybe you wanted to assign c or d?)

Comment: Thank you so much for everyone's help. Really appreciate :) !

Answer (score 0):

You have four variables `x`,`y`,`w`,`z` so you need a kmap with 4x4=16 fields, like the second example in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-of-k-map-karnaugh-map/. For the position of the variables and their negations in the kmap replace A,B,C,D with x,y,w,z in the picture :
[image]

The translation of letters to binary digits is

> Simplify all the terms until no more terms can be simpified, the
> output of the example below in this step is: `['10**', '1*0*', '1**0', '*110']` which is same as `AB' + AC' + AD' + BCD'`

source : https://github.com/zhcHoward/Kmap

So you basically need a square matrix

```
int matrix[4][4];

/*initialize matrix with '0'*/

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = 0;

/* then needed fields to '1' i.e. xy', in most implementations the array is flattened for this  */
```

Source code for a kmap solver is i.e. in http://krunalsiddhapathak.blogspot.com/2013/05/blog-post.html and in **https://github.com/Ghost---Shadow/karnaugh-map-simplifier/blob/master/KarnaughMap/Map.cpp**

For the verfication step ("Demonstrate that,...") see this *.cpp* code **https://github.com/Ghost---Shadow/karnaugh-map-simplifier/blob/master/KarnaughMap/Simplifier.cpp** and for background (POS, SOP, quad, octant,...) **https://github.com/tasnim007/K-Map-Solver----Java-Project**, **https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-of-k-map-karnaugh-map/** and **http://www.nzdl.org/cgi-bin/library?e=d-00000-00---off-0cdl--00-0----0-10-0---0---0direct-10---4-------0-1l--11-en-50---20-about---00-0-1-00-0--4----0-0-11-10-0utfZz-8-00&cl=CL2.4&d=HASHfb0a7f85db79899f86b6a0.8.1.5&gt=1**

Comment: OP’s effort is to print a Karnaugh map, not to solve one.

Comment: No, a kmap with 4 variables x,y,w,z can not be solved with this code

Comment: To whom are you saying no? My comment has nothing to do with whether a Karnaugh map can or cannot be solved with this code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helps! I figured it out!

Comment: @Naruesorn Dechnorachai  Please post the sol'n